# Configuration error when installing MySQL (database initialization failed)

Tags: mysql, database

I installed wanted MySQL programs while installing MySQL 8.0.1 Enterprise Edition.

When I try to apply my configuration settings I keep getting an error that the database initialization has failed. (See the log below for the details.)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Configuration Error Image]

[image: log details image]

Comment: If you are an enterprise customer - why not ask MySQL for support? If you are using it as a personal use - you might want to consider installing the MySQL Community Server.  Also this is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031821/error-during-installation-database-initialization-failed

Comment: Should your 'lower_case_table_names' have the value 0 instead of 0.0?

Comment: Do not use web installer - use offline MSI (mysql-installer-community-8.0.11.0.msi, 230 Mb).